# Accept a persistent tcp connection in Golang Server

Tags: go, tcp, buffer, telnet

I am experimenting with Go - and would like to create a TCP server which I can telnet to, send commands and receive responses.

```
const (
    CONN_HOST = "localhost"
    CONN_PORT = "3333"
    CONN_TYPE = "tcp"
)

func main() {

    listener, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", CONN_HOST, CONN_PORT))
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    defer listener.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicln(err)
        }

        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

    length, err := conn.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    str := string(buffer[:length])

    fmt.Println(conn.RemoteAddr().String())
    fmt.Printf("Received command %d\t:%s\n", length, str)

    switch str {
        case "PING\r\n":
        sendResponse("PONG", conn)
        case "PUSH\r\n":
        sendResponse("GOT PUSH", conn)
    default:
        conn.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("UNKNOWN_COMMAND: %s\n", str)))
    }

    conn.Close() // closes the connection
}

func sendResponse(res string, conn net.Conn) {
    conn.Write([]byte(res+"\n"))
}
```

The above snippet will close the connection every time, kicking me out of the terminal session. But what I actually want, is to be able to keep the connection open for more I/O operations. If I simply remove the `conn.Close()`, then the server appears to hang somewhere as it does not get any more responses.

The way I have resolved this is to have my handleRequest method endlessly loop so that it never exits till it receives a `QUIT\r\n` message. Is this appropriate - or is there a better way of achieving?

```
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    for {
        log.Println("Handling Request")
        buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

        length, err := conn.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicln(err)
        }

        str := string(buffer[:length])

        fmt.Println(conn.RemoteAddr().String())
        fmt.Printf("Received command %d\t:%s\n", length, str)

        switch str {
        case "PING\r\n":
            sendResponse("PONG", conn)
        case "PUSH\r\n":
            sendResponse("GOT PUSH", conn)
        case "QUIT\r\n":
            sendResponse("Goodbye", conn)
            conn.Close()
        default:
            conn.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("UNKNOWN_COMMAND: %s\n", str)))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you need to loop around the read to read more than once. Don't panic on errors, there's no reason to crash your program if the connection closes.

Comment: I think that this is the correct implementation. Just an hint: after you have called `conn.Close()` remeber call a break statement otherwise the for loop will run for ever

Comment: JimB Thanks. Re panicking on errors - I was just doing in dev as I have not built proper error handler yet. And just wanted to capture the error. Tinwor - Good spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second example with the loop is already what you want. You simply loop and read as long as you want (or probably until some read/write timeout or an external cancellation signal).

However it still has an error in it:
TCP gives you a stream of bytes, where it is not guaranteed that one write from a side will yield exactly one read on the other side with the same data length. This means if the client writes `PING\r\n` you could still receive only `PI` in the first read. You could fix that by using a `bufio.Scanner` and always read up to the first newline.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. Taken from `net/http` implementation, wrapping your `net.TCPListener`'s `Accept` method.

`tcpKeepAliveListener{listener.(*net.TCPListener)}`

```
type tcpKeepAliveListener struct {
    *net.TCPListener
}

func (ln tcpKeepAliveListener) Accept() (c net.Conn, err error) {
    tc, err := ln.AcceptTCP()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    tc.SetKeepAlive(true)
    tc.SetKeepAlivePeriod(3 * time.Minute)
    return tc, nil
}
```

Refer : [Link 1](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.7/src/net/http/server.go#L2219) & [Link 2](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.7/src/net/http/server.go#L2599-L2615)

Comment: Not quite what I wanted, but very useful. Thanks